# Why isn't this site called StackOverthrow?

Tags: discussion

....and the cooking SE is called "Seasoned Advice" rather than "SnackOverflow." Seriously, does no one around here appreciate puns?

Comment: The _SnackOverflow_ one made me laugh :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StackExchange sites are kind of notorious for [hating fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).